# Kendo UI: Binding practice

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm not sure what is the best way for my scenario, so I'll explain that first.

I have two datasources. Persons and Groups, each Person-Item has an indicator, to which group it belongs to. The persons are binded to a kendo-grid and the groups to a <ul>. My problem is, that I want  to display a count-number besides the group, which indicates how many persons are in that group - this information is calculated from the persons-datasource and not part of the group itself.

Sorry for that generic question - but I'm really struggling with this...

UPDATE: Here is what I have now:

```
var contactGroupsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "api/contactgroups"
    }
  }
});

$('#contactGroupsList').kendoListView({
    dataSource: contactGroupsDataSource,
    template: "<li class='contactGroupListItem' data-number='${Number}'>${Number} ${Name} (<span data-bind="text: cgcount[1]"></span>) </li>"
});

viewModel = kendo.observable({
        contactsDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "api/contacts"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        id: { type: "string" },
                        FirstName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" },
                        ContactGroupNumber: { type: "integer" }
                    }
                }
            },
            change: function (e) {
                var data = this.data();

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var cg = data[i]["ContactGroupNumber"];
                    viewModel.cgcount.splice([cg - 1], 1, viewModel.cgcount[cg - 1] + 1);
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    console.log(i + 1 + ': ' + viewModel.cgcount[i]);
                }
            }
        }),
        cgcount: new kendo.data.ObservableArray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    });

    kendo.bind($("#contactsGroupContainer"), viewModel);

    contactsListView = $('#contactsList').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: viewModel.contactsDataSource,
        sortable: true,
        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html())
    });
```

Daniel

Comment: can you provide the code you have right now?

Comment: I edited my post with the current code. I tried several different approaches - but I think this one shows what I like to achieve.